# dialog box is never on the top of the page

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-material

I have a page where I have a fixed navbar in right and the content of the page.

in the content of the page I have a button when I click on him it will open a dialog in the center of the page, I'm using Angular Materiel Dialogs for this.

The problem is when I open the dialog the fixed bar is always on the top of the page :

[image]

As you can see the side bar is hiding a part of that dialog box.

And this is the code i use to diplay my dialog box :

```
$mdDialog.show({
                    clickOutsideToClose: true,
                    controller         : DialogController,
                    controllerAs       : 'vm',
                    parent             : $document.find('body').eq(0),
                    templateUrl        : templateUrl,
                    targetEvent        : event
                });
```

As you can see I'm using `$document.find('body').eq(0),` as a parent for the dialog, but why this dialog is never on top of the side bar ?

## jsfiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/jhzawjdb/17/

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override or change the `z-index` on `#sidebar-wrapper` to 0 from 1000.

http://jsfiddle.net/vcpqasyd/

Answer (score 3):

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 0;
}
```

Change `z-index` to `0` and this will correct the modal aka dialog box.